# Dynamic linking directories

Tags: unix, symbolic-link, links

Is there any way I can create a link, that dynamically updates.
My specific situation is, that I have multiple exercises (directories) and I want to link to the latest one:

```
exercises/
│   exercise_01/
│   │    files ...
│   exercise_02/
│   │    files ...
│   exercise_03/
│   │    files ...
│   exercise_latest/ -> exercise_03/
```

so if I `cd exercises/exercise_latest` it always goes to the latest one.
Adding a new directory `exercise_04` would make the link point to that one instead.

The solutions I can come up with are:

1. A cron job that runs once a minute and relinks if it detects a new directory.
2. Not make it a link but a script that `cd`s to the latest directory.
3. Manually maintaining it

Neither solution is particularly elegant. `1.` is really inefficient and potentially too slow. I cannot copy files into `2.`. `3.` defeats the purpose.

Versioned software releases do something similar.
For example `python3` always links to the latest Python 3 version.
They however probably update every time a new version is installed.

Is there anything I can do that is more elegant than my ideas?

Comment: What about combining option 2 with creating another script that will copy files into the latest directory? That seems like the simplest and most robust solution.

Comment: A fourth option is to incorporate the updating of `exercise_latest` into the creation of a new subdirectory, rather than trying to maintain it when you need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is creating a launchctl / launchd agent which can listen to files. This is macOS specific, but there are similar solutions for Linux.

```plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.exercise_listener.plist</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
        <string>/path/to/exercises/.ln_monitor.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/exercises/</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/path/to/exercises/.ln_monitor.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/path/to/exercises/.ln_monitor.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This executes a Python script (`.ln_monitor.py`)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
from pathlib import Path
import time


DIR = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
LINK_ROOTS = ['exercise']
VERBOSE = True


def cprint(*args):
    if VERBOSE:
        print(*args)


def main():
    for root in LINK_ROOTS:
        regex = r'^' + root + r'_\d+$'
        matches = [
            directory for directory in DIR.iterdir()
            if directory.is_dir() and
            re.match(regex, directory.name)]
        match_link = DIR / root
        if matches:
            match = sorted(matches)[-1]
            cprint(f'link to {match.name}')
            if match_link.is_symlink():
                if match_link.resolve() == match:
                    cprint('is already linked')
                    continue
                match_link.unlink()
                cprint('unlinking')
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                cprint('no link yet')
            match_link.symlink_to(match)
            cprint('linked')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the `LINK_ROOTS` here contain all the files that are to be linked. All files matching matching a link root with an underscore and any numbers behind will match, the greatest one will be linked to the link root.

so if `LINK_ROOTS = ['exercise']` the greatest one will be linked like this `exercise -> exercise_04`.

This is not a perfect solution, but it works quite reliably and is not super inefficient.